# How do test runtime exception scenario using JUnit

Tags: junit

I have below class which I need to test. I am able to test the class but how do I test the exception scenario in this case, as  I can not mock `ObjectMapper` class.

```
package xyz.util;

import ...

public class JsonConverter {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper;

    static {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    }

    private JsonConverter() {}

    public static String toJson(Object object) {

        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new AppplicationRuntimeException("Exception while converting object to JSON", e);
        }
    }


    public static <T> T toObject(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(jsonString, clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AppRuntimeException("Exception while converting JSON to Object", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In junit 5 you have assert.withThrowing. In 4 you have attribute in test annotation.

Comment: but how do I mock static member `static ObjectMapper`

Comment: Don't mock the mapper. Just invoke the method with parameters to  force the exception being thrown

Answer (score 0):

If you can - eliminate static calls. For example, by explicitly injecting `ObjectMapper` to the class under test through constructor:

```
public class JsonConverter {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public JsonConverter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
       this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    // rest of the code
}
```

However, if changing the code is not an option, you can use [Powermock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method) to mock static calls with exceptions.

Also, for asserting different exceptional scenarios in combination with JUnit you can use [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#exception-assertion) fluent API.